# Screen not detected on startup

Tags: boot, 18.04, intel-graphics

I've got a NUC7PJYH running xubuntu 18.04 which is connected through hdmi-1 (there are 2 hdmi connections) to a TV.

The UEFI splash screen and UEFI configuration screen work fine, also grub, and even the "check disk for defects" from the live usb - they all show on screen without any problem.

But when starting xubuntu (either as live session, or installed on disk) makes the screen lose signal before I get to see any splash screen of system loading, and I have to restart the TV, or reinsert the hdmi connector for my desktop \ login screen to show up.

This also happens with Ubuntu (not just xubuntu).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a [bug in the board](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105887) (hdmi level shifter), it got fixed for the drm driver provided with the 4.18 kernel, and got backported to 4.14 and 4.17. Installing Ubuntu 18.10 should fix this issue.